How to format numbers with thousand separators and 2 decimal places in Apache Superset (ie: 1,000,000.30)
Apache Superset
in format number, I only see some format such as ,.3f or $,.2f. I can insert .2f but cannot insert ,.2f. It does not allow to input ",".
As I need the number format in "320,000.45". Please help to advise the solution to have that format.
Thanks so much!
enter image description here
I want to have number format in "320,000.45"
I Tried to use CSS code ".thousands-separator, .decimal-separator" in Edit CSS at Dashboard but not work>

In config.py (or in superset_config.py) you should use the following settings for d3 formatting:
D3_FORMAT = {
    "decimal": ".",
    "thousands": ",",
    "currency": ["$", ""],
    "grouping": [3],
}

Also, you might check that you are using 'us' locale.
Restart superset on your machine to apply changes, choose ',.2f' in value formatting selector. Now numbers should look like expected "384,250.00".
